# when i use two function in two different id Show this error.

Tags: javascript, html

```
Call Class:

function changeFunc() 
      {
        var e = document.getElementById("select_func"); 
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;  
        $('#panel1').find ('dl').removeAttr ('class').addClass(strUser)
      }
function changeFun() 
      {
       var er = document.getElementById("select_fun"); 
       var strUs = er.options[er.selectedIndex].value;   
       $('#panel2').find ('dl').removeAttr ('class').addClass(strUs)
      }
```

I use this code to call two different classes in select tag.
 Uncaught ReferenceError: change_Fun is not defined.

Comment: <select id="select_func" onchange="changeFunc(this.id);">
<option value="list_one">Theme1</option>
<option value="change">Theme2</option>
</select>

Comment: The error message says `change_Fun`, but the name of the function is `changeFun`. See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery library is not loaded correctly. add below code before `<Select>` tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel1">
          <dl class="list_one">
     <dt><img src="image/exam.png" alt="exam.png"/></dt>
     <dd><input type="text" placeholder="Text 1"/></dd>   
            <dt><img src="image/exam1.png" alt="exam.png"/></dt>
         <dd><p>Text 1</p></dd>  
            <dt><img src="image/exam.png" alt="exam.png"/></dt>
            <dd><img src="image/exam2.png" alt="exam2.png"/></dd>  
            <dt><img src="image/exam2.png" alt="exam3.png"/></dt>    
</dl>
<dl class="change">
</dl>